# C - stdin to variables

Tags: c, variables, get, line, stdin

I want to create program which can read lines from standard input and interpret each line as two integer numbers separated by space. Later I will use shared library to work with those numbers . Before I start I would like to know, what is the best way to parse numbers from lines. Something like combination of "getline" and storing numbers to variables? I store numbers only until next numbers are given.

Comment: Are these number `int`s? If so, `scanf("%d %d", &first, &second)` is what you're looking for.

Comment: In my case I have to check whether input are ints, if so, then I use functions from shared lib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to extract integers from a string,use

```
sscanf(arr,"%d %d",&num1,&num2);
```

Where `arr` is the array of char containing data from which you want to extract two integers and `num1` and `num2` are two `int` variables.

Or else you can directly scan two `int`s using

```
scanf("%d %d",&num1,&num2);
```

It is better to check if `scanf` (or `sscanf`) is successful. Both of these will return 2(in your case) if they are successful. So just check that using something like:

```
if(scanf("%d %d",&num1,&num2)==2)
//successful
else
//failed
```

Or if you use `sscanf`,

```
if(sscanf(arr,"%d %d",&num1,&num2)==2)
//successful
else
//failed
```